# How should I find the argument when a equals zero with complex numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know how to plot an Argand diagram and I think I know how to find the argument usually, but I've done some looking around to be certain of my answers and found what seems to be conflicting information regarding the argument of purely imaginary numbers (for example, $-2i$).

My textbook gives the example of $\arg(-5j) = -\pi/2$, which makes sense to me as I was told to take the angle as a negative, measured clockwise and in radians. On the diagram, a pure negative imaginary number would be $-90$ degrees ($-\pi/2$ radians) from the real numbers line.

However, I've done some looking online and found two sources which insist it's $3*\pi/2$, and I'm not sure why. Links provided:
http://www.convertalot.com/complex_arithmetical_calculator.html
http://www.mathamazement.com/Lessons/Pre-Calculus/06_Additional-Topics-in-Trigonometry/complex-numbers-in-polar-form.html (Example 1 d).

I'm guessing my textbook is correct as it seems to make the most sense and would be the more trustworthy source, but I have a feeling I'm missing something important considering two different sources came to the same conclusion.

Comment: $\frac{3\pi}{2} = \frac{-\pi}{2} $ subtract $2 \pi$ from $\frac{3\pi}{2}$

Comment: Would there be a preferred answer? Wouldn't the different value of 3pi/2 and -pi/2 cause problems?

Comment: There really isn't that big of a problem. As long as we know we are working in modulo $2\pi$ per se, we know exactly which angle the argument corresponds to. It merely is a matter of convenience. The intervals $[0,2\pi)$ and $(-\pi,\pi]$ are much easier to work with than say, $[\pi/4,\pi/4+2\pi).$